# Spring Boot slow XHR transfer rate

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, xmlhttprequest, data-transfer

Im scratching my head over an performance issue with simple xhr requests in Spring BOOT. (2.2.4.RELEASE).
The application is started as a fat jar, with an embedded tomcat webserver. (I have tried undertow as well, no difference).

The request is paging a large resultset in 500 entries per request. Resulting in response-payload size of 500 kb.

1. The requests are filtered, using an OncePerRequestFilter for JWT
   authentication.**12 - 16 milliseconds**
2. Then the default filter filterchain with 12 standard filters is executed.  **2 milliseconds**
3. The data is fetched from a mysql database and wrapped in a Page object.              **15 milliseconds**
4. Transerring the data.   **3 seconds??**

Even running the application from localhost the transfer of 500kb takes 1 second? What can i possibly debug to improve this performance.

For reference the timings from the browser:
[image]

*edit:*
the transfer rates of the server are

```
Server: goetel GmbH - Göttingen (id = 23610)
    ISP: #####
 Latency:     8.27 ms   (1.38 ms jitter)
 Download:   6051.81 Mbps (data used: 6.5 GB)                               
 Upload:     306.34 Mbps (data used: 138.4 MB)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for what it is worth, I found a workaround to this. This means I still do not have an explanation for the slow transfer speed. However, in order to workaround this, I have limited the amount of data which I proactively retreive from the server. The rest of the data is loaded reactively, when the user needs it. Sadly this means a loss of some functionality, but it seems the only solution for now.